# C# storing a string value from textbox and calling that variable

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am trying to write a C# based winform to do a several automated text entry processes as part of my work. I wish to have certain things entered into textboxes, saving me from doing it manually.

I am able to store the inputted data from a textbox as a string variable but I wish to know how I could call this upon clicking on a seperate textbox. Thus "copying" the data inside one box and placing it elsewhere, on several occasions.

I am not 100% sure this is how the string should be stored but this is my attempt:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string chattextbox;
    }
```

I want the stored string variable to be entered below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.OpenForms["Loginwindow"].BringToFront();
}
```

After bringing the window to the front I wish to call the data from the string variable and have it KeyPress "Enter"

Hope I have made it clear as to what I am trying to do.

Thanks all

Answer (score 6):

In your TextChanged event handler, you have a string variable declared, but you're not assigning anything to it at this point.  To save it off, you need to do this:

```
string chattextbox; // member variable or property in your class

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chattextbox = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Note that chattextbox must be a member variable in your Form class, otherwise, if you have the variable declared in the scope of the method (like in your code), it will be gone when the method returns.

You actually don't need to save it off in this way though, it will be accessible in the `textBox.Text` value at pretty much any time in the form.  A lot of Winforms controls have a `Text` property which holds the string value shown in the control, whether it's a button, textbox, label, etc.  You can most likely remove this TextChanged handler completely, and just implement your button1_Click (see below).

In your button1_Click handler, you can get the value like this.  To pass the value to your other window, you'll need a property on the other window you can assign, or you'll need to pass it in a constructor before showing it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Loginwindow.SomeProperty = textBox1.Text; // Set the string value on your other form somehow ???
    Application.OpenForms["Loginwindow"].BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informed answer. Will post back when I have sorted things

Answer (score 3):

Here, you are not assigning the value of the textbox to the string, just initializing a string variable.

```
Private Void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string chattextbox;
    chattextbox=textBox1.Text;
}
```